# how to convert video into webm format using ffmpeg in centos

Tags: linux, centos, ffmpeg

**how to convert video into webm format using ffmpeg and libvpx in centos**

I have install ffmpeg and libvpx in centos.but it's doesn't convert mp4 format into webm format. but in windows i have check, it's working fine. what's wrong with my code / installation.how to find that.The code below,

**FFMPEG path**

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg
```

**Convert Code**

```
$cmd1= "$ffmpeg -i $video -c:v libvpx -crf 10 -b:v 1M -c:a libvorbis $webmpath";
    $cmdstr = $cmd1;
    $locale = 'en_IN.UTF-8';
    setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
    putenv('LC_ALL='.$locale);
    exec($cmd1);
```

**console output while run ffmpeg command**

```
root@ip-104-238-95-12 [~]# ffmpeg
FFmpeg version 0.6.5, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
built on Jan 29 2012 17:52:15 with gcc 4.4.5 20110214 (Red Hat 4.4.5-6)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --incdir=/usr/include --disable-avisynth --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC' --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdirac --enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-libfaadbin --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-swscale --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab

  libavutil     50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1

  libavcodec    52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2

  libavformat   52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2

  libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0

  libavfilter    1.19. 0 /  1.19. 0

  libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0

  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0

Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...

Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffmpeg'
root@ip-104-238-95-12 [~]#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ffmpeg` version packaged in CentOS is too old to understand some of the options provided.

I'd suggest you to download a more recent version.
The easy way is to download the latest static build for your platform, you can find it here: http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/ (choose 32 or 64 bit depending on your arch).

For instance:

```
$ cd /opt/
$ wget http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/releases/ffmpeg-release-64bit-static.tar.xz
$ tar xvf ffmpeg-release-64bit-static.tar.xz
$ ln -s /opt/ffmpeg-2.6.3-64bit-static /opt/ffmpeg
```

And use `/opt/ffmpeg/ffmpeg` rather than `/usr/bin/ffmpeg`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23947/discussion-on-answer-by-apaul-how-to-convert-video-into-webm-format-using-ffmpeg).